# custom camera textureView not adjusting to landscape mode

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera2

I am making a custom android camera app. So far, the only problem I have is getting the `textureView` to adjust when in landscape mode (turning the camera 90 degrees). The view comes out distorted and not in the right orientation. Portrait mode works fine. I am not sure if the problem is in the `setupCamera()` method, `sensorToDeviceRotation()` method, or the `configureTransform()` method. I haven't implemented anything to actually take the photo yet. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT/UPDATE: I updated my code to add the improvements. The original problem still persists despite this. I am using a Pixel XL to test this code. I am still not sure what the problem is.

homePage.java

```
public class homePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION = 123;
    private String mCameraId;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startPreview();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();

        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch(requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Certain permissions needed to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCamera() {

        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
            return true;
        }else {

            AlertDialog camAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(homePage.this).create();
            camAlert.setTitle("Alert");
            camAlert.setMessage("there is no usable camera");
            camAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            camAlert.show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                int totalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
                int rotatedWidth = width;
                int rotatedHeight = height;

                if(swapRotation) {
                    rotatedWidth = height;
                    rotatedHeight = width;
                }

                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if(mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }

    private void connectCamera() {

        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "non-marshmellow device permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            }

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set up camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("cameraString");
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();

        try {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics,
                                              int deviceOrientation) {

        int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
        return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    }

    private void configureTransform (int width, int height) {

        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        final int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        final RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
        final RectF buffetRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        final float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        final float centerY = viewRect.centerY();

        if(Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            buffetRect.offset(centerX - buffetRect.centerX(), centerY - buffetRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, buffetRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            final float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) height / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) width / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);

        }else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
            matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }
//=====added code from suggestions=======================
    public interface CameraModule {
        void onOrientationChanged(int orientation);
    }

    CameraModule mCurrentModule;
    private MyOrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;
    private int mLastRawOrientation = OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;

    private class MyOrientationEventListener extends OrientationEventListener {
        public MyOrientationEventListener(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if(orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
                return;
            mLastRawOrientation = orientation;
            mCurrentModule.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
        }
    }
//========================================================================
    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();

        for(Size option: choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        hasCamera();
        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);

        mOrientationListener = new MyOrientationEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();

        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            connectCamera();
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention your exact problem?

Comment: @Mandy8055 when I turn my phone 90 degrees to get the landscape view, the textureView does not adjust correctly. The view becomes stretched out and rotates the wrong way.

Comment: I don't think I am implementing your suggestions correctly. I get many errors within my code.

Comment: Debugging must be your area of forte. Your problem was mainly about the **Orientation** of `TextureView`. I have implemented the important method and told you how it worked.

Comment: I have put forth the answer explaining every points.Take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. The only issue I come up with now is the line with 'mCurrentModule'. It returns the error: cannot resolve symbol 'mCurrentModule'. I tried adding 'CameraModule mCurrentModule;' like your project did, but it did not help.

Comment: Which line this issue arises?

Comment: 'mCurrentModule.onOrientationChanged(orientation);'

Comment: Check this out Add this as an interface in your project:https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/CameraModule.java

Comment: Does it worked?

Comment: The code has no errors anymore but the textureView still doesn't change into landscape view correctly.

Comment: Are you trying it on a device or an emulator? It worked for me. I have retested it again.

Comment: I am using a Pixel XL

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @HarnanRazo please do not use my name in the question. Question is for general purpose. Do not desecrate its piousness by putting a name(as it can be answered by any member of SO not me only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by eliminating the `configureTransform()` method, the `cameraModule` module, and the `myOrientationEventListener()` class. I replaced it with the `transformImage()` method. I then called this method in the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` and the `onResume()` method.

The problem I might have been facing in the old code was the fact that I was calling the `configureTransform()`method in the wrong places. I got the answer from looking at this post: [Android Camera2 Preview is rotated 90deg while in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536798/android-camera2-preview-is-rotated-90deg-while-in-landscape?rq=1)

and this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvS3iGKhQ_g

These sources explain the topic far better than me so please look them over if facing a similar issue.

new functioning code:

homePage.java:

```
    public class homePage extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION = 123;
        private String mCameraId;
        private Size mPreviewSize;
        private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;
        private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
        private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
        private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
        static {
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
        }
        private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
        private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                mCameraDevice = camera;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startPreview();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                camera.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                camera.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
        };

        private TextureView mTextureView;
        private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                setupCamera(width, height);
                connectCamera();
                transformImage(width, height);
            }
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               @NonNull String permissions[],
                                               @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            switch(requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Certain permissions needed to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        private boolean hasCamera() {

            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
                return true;
            }else {

                AlertDialog camAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(homePage.this).create();
                camAlert.setTitle("Alert");
                camAlert.setMessage("there is no usable camera");
                camAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                camAlert.show();
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                    CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                    if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                            CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                    int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    int totalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                    boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
                    int rotatedWidth = width;
                    int rotatedHeight = height;

                    if(swapRotation) {
                        rotatedWidth = height;
                        rotatedHeight = width;
                    }

                    mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                    mCameraId = cameraId;
                    return;
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void closeCamera() {
            if(mCameraDevice != null) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
        }

        private void connectCamera() {

            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                            //Toast.makeText(this, "non-marshmellow device permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                } else {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                }

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void startPreview() {
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            try {
                mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

                mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                        new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                try {
                                    session.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set up camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void startBackgroundThread() {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("cameraString");
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
            mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
        }

        private void stopBackgroundThread() {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();

            try {
                mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
                mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
                mBackgroundHandler = null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics,
                                                  int deviceOrientation) {

            int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
            return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
        }
    //================new method====================================
        private void transformImage(int width, int height) {
            if(mPreviewSize == null || mTextureView == null) {
                return;
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            RectF textureRectF = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
            RectF previewRectF = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            float centerX = textureRectF.centerX();
            float centerY = textureRectF.centerY();

            if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
                previewRectF.offset(centerX - previewRectF.centerX(),
                        centerY - previewRectF.centerY());
                matrix.setRectToRect(textureRectF, previewRectF, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
                float scale = Math.max((float)width / mPreviewSize.getWidth(),
                        (float)height / mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
                matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
            }
            mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
        }
   //=============================================================== 

        private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

            @Override
            public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
                return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                        (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
            }
        }

        private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
            List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();

            for(Size option: choices) {
                if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                        option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
            if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
                return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
            } else {
                return choices[0];
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

            hasCamera();
            mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            startBackgroundThread();

            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                connectCamera();
                transformImage(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            closeCamera();
            stopBackgroundThread();
            super.onPause();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this(Add this `private` class in your **HomePage.java**):Notice the `onOrientationChanged()` method can be applied to `xmls` also: 
We keep the last known orientation. So if you first orient the camera then point the camera to floor or sky, then also `TextureView` and `Camera` have the correct orientation.

```
private MyOrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;
// The degrees of the device rotated clockwise from its natural orientation.
private int mLastRawOrientation= OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN;
//Don't forget to add **mOrientationListener = new MyOrientationEventListener(this);** on your onCreate() method

private class MyOrientationEventListener
        extends OrientationEventListener {
    public MyOrientationEventListener(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


 @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
        mLastRawOrientation = orientation;
        mCurrentModule.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
    }
}
```

For more information you can catch this link up:[Camera Example](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/CameraActivity.java)

Comment: How would I implement this into my code? I don't think I fully understand your suggestion. Could you please explain it?